# what is $\mathbb E[W(t)^n]$ where $W(t)$ is a wiener process?

Tags: brownian-motion, expected-value, wiener-measure

What is the expectation of Wiener process raised to the power of $n$ where $W(t)$ is a wiener process or a standard Brownian motion?

E
  (
  W
  (
  t
  )
  
    )
    
      n
    
  
  )

Comment: Do you mean $E(W(t))^{n})$?.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: yes I updated the question @KaboMurphy

Answer (score 2):

In the understanding that $W(t)\sim\mathsf{Norm}(0,t)$ we may conclude that:$$\mathbb{E}W\left(t\right)^{n}=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\
t^{n/2}\left(n-1\right)!! & \text{if }n\text{ is even}
\end{cases}$$

If $n$ is even then: $$\left(n-1\right)!!:=\left(n-1\right)\times\left(n-3\right)\times\cdots\times3\times1$$
Also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different approaches to take for this. One way is to know that since $W_t$ is a standard Wiener process, $W_t$ ~ $N(0, t)$. Then, $W^n_t$ is just a normal random variable with standard deviation $\sqrt t$ raised to the $n$-th power. The expectation can then be found by the moment-generating function (MGF) $M_X(t) = E(e^{tX})$, or specifically for a normal r.v.:
$$M_X(t) = e^{t \mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 t^2}$$

Then, taking the n-th derivative with respect at $t = 0$ will yield the corresponding moment. Notice there is a little bit of a change in variable terminology due to the naming convention of $t$ for MGFs and the $t$ present in the Wiener process $W_t$. Since $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = t$, let's call $t'$ the $t$ of the MGF as such:

$$ M_{W_t} = e^{\frac{1}{2} t {t'}^2}$$

Then, taking the n-th derivative w.r.t. $t'$ and setting $t = 0$ will give the corresponding moment (i.e. the expectation of the Wiener process to the power of $n$).

Another method related to the MGF is to use the characteristic function, but I am not too familiar with that.

Using an important result from stochastic calculus would be to use Ito's Lemma, but this is probably not the best example to demonstrate the power of the Lemma.

Comment: Are you saying that $X^n$ has normal distribution if $X$ has normal distribution with mean $0$?

Comment: No. I'm saying that a standard Wiener process $W_t$ is a normal random variable with parameters $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma^2 = t$. Thus, the power of $W^n_t$ is just a normal random variable with the aforementioned parameters to the $n$-th power, so whatever the $n$-th moment is (which is just the expectation $E[(W_t)^n]$

Comment: But if $W_t$ has normal distribution then $W_t^n$ has not (if $n\neq1$). Still you call it a normal random variable. Where do I misunderstand you then?

Comment: No. $W_t$ ~ $N(0, t)$. However, the moments of normal distributions can be calculated in a standard way (integrals, moment-generating functions, characteristic functions, Ito's lemma). so $E[W_t] = 0$, but $E[W^n_t] = E[X^n]$, where $X$ ~ $N(0, t)$

Comment: I see now. Actually I overlooked the words "...raised to the $n$-th power..." in your answer. Sorry for troubling you.